# How do I get the output of phpinfo() as xml?

Tags: php, xml

Is there a way to achieve this?

I found this function:

```
function phpinfo_array($return=true){
             /* Andale!  Andale!  Yee-Hah! */
             ob_start();
             phpinfo(-1);

             $pi = preg_replace(
             array('#^.*<body>(.*)</body>.*$#ms', '#<h2>PHP License</h2>.*$#ms',
             '#<h1>Configuration</h1>#',  "#\r?\n#", "#</(h1|h2|h3|tr)>#", '# +<#',
             "#[ \t]+#", '#&nbsp;#', '#  +#', '# class=".*?"#', '%&#039;%',
              '#<tr>(?:.*?)" src="(?:.*?)=(.*?)" alt="PHP Logo" /></a>'
              .'<h1>PHP Version (.*?)</h1>(?:\n+?)</td></tr>#',
              '#<h1><a href="(?:.*?)\?=(.*?)">PHP Credits</a></h1>#',
              '#<tr>(?:.*?)" src="(?:.*?)=(.*?)"(?:.*?)Zend Engine (.*?),(?:.*?)</tr>#',
              "# +#", '#<tr>#', '#</tr>#'),
             array('$1', '', '', '', '</$1>' . "\n", '<', ' ', ' ', ' ', '', ' ',
              '<h2>PHP Configuration</h2>'."\n".'<tr><td>PHP Version</td><td>$2</td></tr>'.
              "\n".'<tr><td>PHP Egg</td><td>$1</td></tr>',
              '<tr><td>PHP Credits Egg</td><td>$1</td></tr>',
              '<tr><td>Zend Engine</td><td>$2</td></tr>' . "\n" .
              '<tr><td>Zend Egg</td><td>$1</td></tr>', ' ', '%S%', '%E%'),
             ob_get_clean());

             $sections = explode('<h2>', strip_tags($pi, '<h2><th><td>'));
             unset($sections[0]);

             $pi = array();
             foreach($sections as $section){
               $n = substr($section, 0, strpos($section, '</h2>'));
               preg_match_all(
               '#%S%(?:<td>(.*?)</td>)?(?:<td>(.*?)</td>)?(?:<td>(.*?)</td>)?%E%#',
                 $section, $askapache, PREG_SET_ORDER);
               foreach($askapache as $m)
                   $pi[$n][$m[1]]=(!isset($m[3])||@$m[2]==$m[3])?@$m[2]:array_slice($m,2);
             }

             return ($return === false) ? print_r($pi) : $pi;
```

}

This function returns an array with the data from phpinfo() which looks quite like a hammer-method ;)

But it seems, like phpinfo() provides data that are not to achieve otherwisee.

Now how can I correctly turn this complicated array into valid XML?

Comment: You found a function and that's it? What is your question? What happened when you tried it? Did you get incorrect results? Did you get *no* results? What doesn't work? Please explain.

Comment: I think HTML DOM Parser might be able to achive this (export HTML as XML).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function will return an array.

You can easily turn this into an xml using [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/simplexml), by walking through your array and adding the keys and values.

There are some nice answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5965940/32763).